# Upload multiple files or folders to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

Am I able to upload multiple files and/or folders at a time to Ubuntu One?
I am not interested in downloading the Ubuntu One manager for Windows to sync files; I simply want to sign in to my Ubuntu One storage & upload multiple files (photos, videos, etc) all at once instead of one-by-one.

Comment: I guess you should state more clearly what you want: you want to use the webinterface at [one.ubuntu.com](http://one.ubuntu.com). And you want to be able to select more then one file in the file selection dialog. Right?

Comment: In the web portal upload of folders is still not possible. Because I have no administrator rights on my office computer like probably many others, installing the Ubuntu One client for windows is not possible for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, there is no such option. However, we are scheduled to work on this in early next year, so this should be no more than a few months away.

Comment: Awesome! It is quite cumbersome when trying to upload from computers that you cannot sync with Ubuntu One due to admin rights. Thanks for the update!